# Liferay SSO CAS LDAP

Tags: ldap, liferay, single-sign-on, cas, liferay-6

Good evening, I must make an intranet with Liferay, the most important is to integrate a web application (or 2) already ready with the portal that I will make . These web applications are made ​​in php, so in order not to make each authentication, wanted the user to authenticate to the portal and click on the link to one of these web applications, it will not have to authenticate again for its apps. For this reason I used SSO CAS and I integrated it with Liferay, I still used an LDAP directory to be related to the CAS server to identify users.
My problem is how is the procedure for other web apps, is that users must have the same login and password for partail (Liferay) with the others two apps php? Or I can let each application with their users without the change (because in each app, the user has a login and password different from other apps), that is how the coordination between different words and LGIN passes the various apps (this is a problem of SSO, I misunderstood the principle of work I should implement it) ??

Some clarifications and assistance please??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other webapps need to implement a so called CAS Client. The php one is [here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS):

The php apps will typically redirect non authenticated users to CAS, and after they logged in the webapp retreive a saml token. In that token claims are found that uniquely identify the user. application then typically match the provided claim to their own userstore or apply the concept of a virtual user.

But that is up to the implementer of the webapps.

Comment: What if i have not access in the others webapps? can i pass the cas ticket by url or something like that?

Comment: If the other webapps don't want to participate in the SSO you're out of luck. You can't force them to trust your cas-ticket @El0din